# How to have automatic (or manual) scaling of xticks and yticks with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Basically, I want my curve to be properly fitted onto the graph, as it obviously isn't the case currently. My `xtick` intervals are equal according to pyplot, but they clearly have values that do not match that. I want pyplot to understand that, and I'm not sure why it's forcing the curve to be 'boxed' in a square graph when it has ample space... What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Here is my current code for creating the plot.

```
plt.figure(sheet_name, figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(beam_deformation, '-x')
plt.xticks([sensor[0] for sensor in sensors], [f"{sensor[0]} ({i+1})" for i, sensor in enumerate(sensors)], rotation=20)
plt.xlabel('sensors (position)')
plt.ylabel('Extent of Deformation (in)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide only one array to [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), it gets plotted at `x = [0, 1, 2, ...]`:

> **`x`, `y`:** The horizontal and vertical coordinates of the data points. **`x` values are optional and default to `range(len(y))`.**

So in the current code, `beam_deformation` is assumed to be `y` and gets plotted at `x = [0, 1, 2, ...]`. Then the tick marks get set to `[0.5, 2.9, 5.3, ...]`, but that's unrelated to how the `beam_deformation` points were plotted.

---

To plot the `beam_deformation` points at `x = [0.5, 2.9, 5.3, ...]`, pass the `x` values explicitly to [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

```
x = [float(s[0]) for s in sensors]   # x = [0.5, 2.9, 5.3, ...]
plt.plot(x, beam_deformation, '-x')  # explicitly set x coordinates

plt.xticks(x, [f'{s[0]} ({i+1})' for i, s in enumerate(sensors)], rotation=20)
```

---

Or if you actually do want to plot `beam_deformation` at `x = [0, 1, 2, ...]`, then set the tick locations accordingly:

```
plt.plot(beam_deformation, '-x')     # assume x = [0, 1, 2, ...]

ticks = range(len(beam_deformation)) # since x = [0, 1, 2, ...]
labels = [f'{s[0]} ({i+1})' for i, s in enumerate(sensors)]
plt.xticks(ticks, labels, rotation=20)
```

---

In this case, since your sensor values are all equidistant (2.4 apart), both versions will end up looking the same visually:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that fixed the issue. I have one last question though, since my x axis clearly goes from 0 to 22 and my y axis has a magnitude of 4, I want my graph to reflect those differences in size. Basically, I want my x axis to show 22 ticks, but only have data points at the relevant ticks (where an -x should be plotted). Thank you for your time.

Comment: So does that mean you don't want tick labels like `['0.5 (1)', '2.9 (2)', ...]` anymore? If you just want 22 `xticks`, I think you mean this: `plt.plot(x, beam_deformation, '-x'); plt.xticks(range(23))`

Comment: Yes you are correct. So the labels would be 1 to 22, but the points -x would be in the proper location on the graph and the curve would still be properly displayed. The y and x axis should still have a ratio of 1, so they should have the same intervals in this case.

Comment: This should do it: `plt.plot([float(s[0]) for s in sensors], beam_deformation, '-x'); plt.xticks(range(23))` https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCSxH.png -- It plots `x` at the sensor values, `y` at the beam deformations, and `xticks` at `[0, 1, 2, ..., 22]`.